# Feature detect support for DOMContentLoaded event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, browser-feature-detection, domcontentloaded

Is it possible to detect support for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event?

Method's like Kangax's solution here won't work because `DOMContentLoaded` is not exposed as a property of any element: [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/)

Comment: A dive into something like the jQuery source should be informative.

Comment: Why don't use compatibility table?

Comment: @Mics Cause that's browser detection not feature detection.

Comment: @Pointy jQuery isn't detecting for support they just use `load` as a fallback. Not really what I'm looking for: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L813

Comment: Here's an old forum thread on the subject: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:M_CBoB0m73QJ:objectmix.com/javascript/245908-detect-domcontentloaded-possible.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: I suppose you want to detect the feature before or when the event fires? Or is it acceptable to know when `load' event fires? Because then you can just set a Boolean in the even handlers of those two events.

Comment: @Djizeus That's true, so if someone was looking to just show a list of supported/unsupported features to users that would work, but if they were trying to conditionally load a `DOMContentLoaded` polyfill, that would be pointless, because those events fire only once.

Comment: Considering that there's a library out there dedicated to feature detection [that you might have heard of](http://modernizr.com/), that lists this feature as [undetectable](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables#events), I'd say you're SOL. Just use multiple fallbacks and early exit if one fires.

Answer (score 3):

Just listen for all three events and the first one triggered wins. If the winner is DOMContentLoaded, it's supported. If it hasn't been triggered by the time one of the other two has been triggered, then it's not supported.

```
<script>
    var hasDOMContentLoaded = false,
        ready = false,
        readyMethod = null;

    // Listen for "DOMContentLoaded"
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        hasDOMContentLoaded = true;
        init("DOMContentLoaded");
    });

    // Listen for "onreadystatechange"
    document.onreadystatechange = function () { init("onreadystatechange"); }

    // Listen for "load"
    document.addEventListener("load", function(event) { init("load"); });

    // Gets called after any one of the above is triggered. 
    function init(method) {
        if(!ready) {
            ready = true;
            readyMethod = method;
            go();
        }
    }

    // Page is ready, time is up. 
    // Eitehr DOMContentLoaded has been triggered or it never will.
    function go() {
        console.log("hasDOMContentLoaded: ", hasDOMContentLoaded);
        // My initialization code here
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually & Factually, there is no need for *DOMContentLoaded Event*.
Any script can be used to determine, if the document HTML was completely parsed thanks to the principle of html stream load.

All you have to do, is to put the function (you would otherwise assign to the DOMContentLoaded event) right before the closing tags of your document(s).

It will execute exactly after the last HTML element has been parsed to DOM, and it will execute a bit faster and earlier than the built-in DOMContentLoaded will do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following explanation about [usage of the DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) from the mozilla developer site very useful. At the end it talks about backwardly compatible ways to do achieve the same thing, which I have extracted here (no surprise it concentrates on IE)...

> Internet Explorer 8 supports the readystatechange event, which can be
>   used to detect when the DOM is ready. In earlier versions of Internet
>   Explorer, this state can be detected by repeatedly trying to execute
>   document.documentElement.doScroll("left");, as this snippet will throw
>   an error until the DOM is ready.

Comment: IE was the first and only UA to have equipped you with the ready state of document and other document elements who's Property values are:
Type: String > states: *uninitialized* (Object is not initialized with data.) > *loading* (Object is loading its data.) > *loaded* (Object has finished loading its data.) > *interactive* (User can interact with the object even though it is not fully loaded.) > *complete* (Object is completely initialized.) The *interactive* state of the document is a predecessor of DOMContentLoaded and is available in all versions of IE since 1997 or IE4.0.